# Why is the following sequence of equalities true?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

I am trying to understand the answer posted in [composition of two measurable function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/205163/composition-of-two-measurable-function/205178#205178).

*Note that $$(\chi_A \circ \Psi^{-1})^{-1}((.5,1.5)) = (\chi_A \circ \Psi^{-1})^{-1}(\{ 1 \}) = \Psi(\chi_A^{-1}(\{ 1 \})) = \Psi(A)$$ which is nonmeasurable, so $\chi_A \circ \Psi^{-1}$ cannot be measurable.*

How did $\chi_A \circ \Psi^{-1}$ cannot be measurable come about?

Comment: Any ideas anyone?